# Samsung Galaxy Pop got stuck while updating to Jelly Bean

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, reboot

My *Samsung Galaxy Pop* (GT-S5570) got stuck while updating to Jelly Bean with Cyanogenmod 10.1. It sticks at the Samsung logo at the start. What can I do to get it working again?

Comment: Did you perform a wipe before flashing? Which ROM has been on the device before? Can you still boot into recovery?

Comment: A common mistake - wipe cache an dalvik-cache from recovery and reboot. Should be okay then.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the forum section of your device with whatever site you use and find the links for Odin and Samsung's official Kit Kat release for your device and flash that using Odin. Then you will be stock once again then accept the update and all should be fine.